# Create a Link from a <span>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get this to work, but I don't know how to get the value from `<span class="lsku"> value </span>` and add it as a suffix after the the url. ex: **domain.com/link-*value***

```js
function changespan() {
  var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span.lsku');
  for (var i = spans.length; i--;) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = $(".link2part").attr('href');
    spans[i].appendChild(a).appendChild(a.previousSibling);
  }
}

changespan();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="domain.com/link-" class="link2part"></a>

<div class="divTableBody">
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell"><span class="lsku">50</span></div>
    <div class="divTableCell">name 1</div>
    <div class="divTableCell"><span class="linkview">view</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="divTableBody">
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell"><span class="lsku">60</span></div>
    <div class="divTableCell">name 2</div>
    <div class="divTableCell"><span class="lsku">view</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[VIEW IT WITH JSFIDDLE.NET](https://jsfiddle.net/acxel305/y76ezL9x/30/#&togetherjs=apVeL5ONI7)

Comment: In your second div block, there are two spans with the class `lsku`. Should the second one be `linkview`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you could set the value property to the span tag, and pass this property at this section:

```
a.href = $(".link2part").attr('href');
```

Like this:

```
a.href = $(".link2part").attr('href' + 'value');
```

And the span tag should recive the value property with the value data you want. Like this:

```
<div class="divTableCell"><span class="lsku" value="view">view</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your example has a typo and in the second block of divs the second span should have the class `linkview` instead of `lsku`. If so, then the following will work.

```js
$('span.linkview').html(function(i, h) {
  return $("<a/>", {
    html: h,
    href: 'domain.com/link-' + $(this).closest('div.divTableRow').find('span.lsku').text()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="domain.com/link-" class="link2part"></a>

<div class="divTableBody">
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell"><span class="lsku">50</span></div>
    <div class="divTableCell">name 1</div>
    <div class="divTableCell"><span class="linkview">view</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="divTableBody">
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell"><span class="lsku">60</span></div>
    <div class="divTableCell">name 2</div>
    <div class="divTableCell"><span class="linkview">view</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `textContent` or `innerText`:

```js
function changespan() {
  var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span.lsku');
  for (var i = spans.length; i--;) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = $(".link2part").attr('href');
    spans[i].appendChild(a);
    a.href = a.href + spans[i].textContent;
    a.textContent = spans[i].textContent;
  }
}

changespan();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="domain.com/link-" class="link2part"></a>

<div class="divTableBody">
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell"><span class="lsku">50</span></div>
    <div class="divTableCell">name 1</div>
    <div class="divTableCell"><span class="linkview">view</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="divTableBody">
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell"><span class="lsku">60</span></div>
    <div class="divTableCell">name 2</div>
    <div class="divTableCell"><span class="lsku">view</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```